# Converting JSONObject to Java Object

Tags: java, spring, rest, json

I made a rest call to a service and stored the response in a `JSONObject`. However, I am trying to convert it to a class object and getting errors. Here's my code:

```
RestOperations operations = /*initalize*/;
String body = /*build request body*/;
String resourceResponse = operations.postForObject(/* url */, body, String.class);
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resourceResponse);
UserIdentifier userIdentifier = (UserIdentifier) jsonResponse.get("userIdentifier");
```

Here's what the response looks like:

```
{
  "userIdentifier": {
    "uid": "ee63a52cda7bf411dd8603ac196951aa77",
    "code": "63a5297e7bf411dd8603ac196951aa77",
    "retailId": "860658787",
    "pointOfEntry": "RETAIL"
  },
  "resultCode": true
}
```

And here's what the `UserIdentifier` class looks like:

```
public class UserIdentifier {
    private String uid;
    private String code;
    private String retailId;

    public UserIdentifier() {

    }

    public UserIdentifier(String uid, String code, String retailId) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.code = code;
        this.retailId = retailId;
    }

    public String getuid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setuid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getcode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setcode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getretailId() {
        return retailId;
    }

    public void setretailId(String retailId) {
        this.retailId = retailId;
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to app.identity.UserIdentifier
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1:** Here's the attempt at using gson from the answers:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String body = /*build request body*/;
String resourceResponse = operations.postForObject(/* url */, body, String.class);
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resourceResponse);
UserIdentifier userIdentifier = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse.getString("userIdentifier"), UserIdentifier.class);
```

But I get the error:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["userIdentifier"] not a string.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:658) ~[json-20140107.jar:na]
```

Comment: Use UserIdentifier convention instead of userIdentifier to match with class name. I hope it will work

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was. Needed to extract the jsonobject instead of getting the string. Here was the line that fixed the issue:

```
UserIdentifier userIdentifier = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse.getJSONObject("userIdentifier").toString(), UserIdentifier.class);
```

Comment: Can this not be done using org.Json.JSONObject?

Answer (score 12):

You may need use gson

```
class Name{
    String resultCode;
    UserIdentifier useridentifier;
    //getters
    
}
```

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
Name name=gson.fromJson(jsonString,Name.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

the things is that you can't cast the object that return in the get method like this, One solution could be this, using `GSON` library:

```
RestOperations operations = /*initalize*/;
String body = /*build request body*/;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String resourceResponse = operations.postForObject(/* url */, body, String.class);
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resourceResponse);
String jsonUserIdentifier = jsonResponse.getString("userIdentifier");
UserIdentifier userIdentifier = gson.fromJson(jsonUserIdentifier , UserIdentifier.class);
```

Comment: edited my post to try this solution but still getting an error

Answer (score -1):

Use Gson library

```
Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().create();

UserIdentifier userIdentifier=gson.fromJson(jsonString,UserIdentifier.class);
```

In your case jsonString is **resourceResponse**

For details study [Gson documentation](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)

Comment: I get the error `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["userIdentifier"] not a string.
 at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:658)`

Comment: Are you using Gson now?