# Java method parameter and return class object

Tags: java

I am trying to abstract the code in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210070/converting-jsonobject-to-java-object) into a util class. Here's the util class method:

```
private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

public static Class getResponseObject(String resourceResponse, String jsonObject, Class responseClass) {
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resourceResponse);
    String jsonResponseToString = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(jsonObject).toString();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonResponseToString, responseClass.getClass());
}
```

And this is the call from another class:

```
UserIdentifier userIdentifier = ServiceClientUtil.getResponseObject(resourceResponse,
                                                                    "userIdentifier",
                                                                    UserIdentifier.class);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:(68, 76) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class cannot be converted to app.identity.UserIdentifier
```

How do I pass in a class object and return the same class object?

Comment: That error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in this scenario you actually want to use something other than `Class`.  Be careful though: it only makes sense to serialize key-value pairs (or an object representation of such) into a JSON value, since a raw `Integer` is not valid JSON.

What we can do is change the signature of your method to take in any object, and since `Class` can be typed, that becomes easier to do.

The signature of your method would be (untested):

```
public static <T> T getResponseObject(String resourceResponse,
                                      String jsonObject,
                                      Class<T> responseClass)
```

This way, we can ensure that the type we pass to this method is an instance of what we get.  Remember:  I'm not guaranteeing that this approach will work for flat values such as `Integer`s, but it should ideally work for any other custom object that you create.

Comment: no this is not what i want because i am trying to make this a reusable method. So i want to be able to pass in any type of class for the `responseClass` and get that returned. For example, I should be able to pass in `Integer.class` and get that returned. I was just using the `UserIdentifier` as an example

Comment: @Richard:  I don't think `Integer` is going to work the way you want it to work but I've revised my answer.

Comment: perfect, this worked exactly like i wanted. Thank you