# Passing ArrayList of JsonObjects through intents

Tags: android, android-intent

How do I pass ArrayList of JSONObjects from RecyclerView's viewholder to another activity through intents?

Comment: You can Serialize your Model and then you can pass with Intent , for more help share your code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just ArrayList of strings you can use

> intent.putStringArrayListExtra()

if it is ArrayList of objects make your object class Parcelable and use

> intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()

Comment: it says : ArrayList<JSONObject> cannot be converted to ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>

Comment: Convert your JSONObject to java object  like descriptive here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210070/converting-jsonobject-to-java-object  then use Parcelable approach

Answer (score 0):

Create Serialize your Model and create getter, setter method for all parameter which you have required. Add all model into a list of model and then use below the line.

```
intent.putExtra("listModel",modelist);
startActivity(intent);
```